# Is there a way to use {@select } tag inside array in dust?

Tags: dust.js

Here is the code snippet I tried to achieve index based selection of elements from an array:

```
{#result}
  {@select key={$idx}}
     {@lte value=3}
       <p>{notes}</p>
         <p style="color:grey;">{createdBy}-{createdDate}</p>
     {/lte}
  {/select}
{/result}
```

But above code throws error "**SyntaxError: Expected end tag for result but it was not found**". Can anyone please suggest any fix for this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is the curly braces surrounding `$idx`. Dust references in parameters don't use curly braces (e.g. `{@select key=$idx}`) or they must have quotes around them (e.g. `{@select key="{$idx}"}`). So, your template would look something like:

```
{#result}
  {@select key=$idx}
     {@lte value=3}
       <p>{name}</p>
         <p style="color:grey;">{createdBy}-{createdDate}</p>
     {/lte}
  {/select}
{/result}
```